# Gettext genitive

Tags: php, gettext

Let's say I want to display the following text to the user:

"John's car"

I'm using gettext to output it:

```
sprintf(_("%s's car"), $firstName)
```

The obvious problem is that, if the first name of the user ends in an S, we'll get something like this:

"James's car" (should be "James' car")

How do I solve that problem, especially considering that other languages might pose a similar challenge (different genitives depending on word ending or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: write a function with an explicit `if` to get the genitive form for a name, and print that instead.  I'd provide an example but you haven't indicated what language we're talking about!

Comment: Programming language: PHP. Human languages: 30 or so different languages - which ones I don't know yet, but probably mostly European languages. The problem is that, while it's easy enough to handle English, I might run into other languages that have very different ways of handling genitives. So my question is, how do people usually handle this kind of problem?

Comment: Turns out that "James's car" is actually a valid alternative to "James' car", so that solves the English case. As for the rest of the languages, I hope the translators will manage to handle it.